# Как написать правильно написать такой скрипт?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть поле к примеру типа text. И я хочу что бы по нажатию кнопки оно становилось доступным к редактированию. Как такое можно сделать?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/show/

Comment: Для этого используется атрибут [contenteditable](http://htmlbook.ru/html/attr/contenteditable)

Comment: А я бы ставил http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/disabled и убирал по клику

Comment: А что вы уже сделали для решения проблемы? Что именно не получилось?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
  
$(function(){
$('body').on('click', '.knopka', function(){ 
    
  if($('.pole-1').attr('disabled')==='disabled'){
      
    $('.pole-1').prop('disabled', false);
    $('.knopka').text('Закончить редактирование');
    }
  else {
    $('.pole-1').prop('disabled', true);
    $('.knopka').text('Редактировать');
    }
                     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form accept-charset="UTF-8">
  <input class="pole-1" type="text" disabled="disabled">
  <button class="knopka"  data="0">Редактировать</button>
</form>
```